# I need intranet users to run an application in Firefox, certain links should open in IE8. OS is Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, activex

I investigated activeX object but it seems there is no chance to make Firefox understand activeX. Any ideas please ?

Comment: This the opposite of cross browser compatibility which is what you should be striving for. "certain links should open in IE8"?  What do you mean by this?  A browser does not call another browser when you click a link so are you asking for a desktop application that calls browsers by link?  You really should attack the core issue instead of going this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless they need to open from the web page, you could create shortcut for the links that need to open in IE8 and include the browser in the shorcut "iexplorer http://some.url"

Comment: Fact is I need to open the links (to some special web appliaction) from the webpage. This is really not my idea :-)))

Comment: it doesn't seem possible